# Django simple URL Mapping issue

Tags: django, django-urls

Have a small issue and wondering if some one can help me out.

I have a text search box like this that

```
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="/library/search/">
          <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="q" name="P" type="text" placeholder="Book Search"">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

When I type in a word and hit submit a URL is generated as follows,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/library/search/?P=Harry+Potter
```

In the URLs.py I have something like this

```
url(r'^search/(?P<search_result>[\w|\W.@+-]+)/$', views.search_view, name='search_view')
```

However the above url is not being matched by the regex statement. If I manually remove the ?P= from the url it works fine.

I have tried some of the following combination and they didn't work either

```
url(r'^search/(?P(.*)<search_result>[\w|\W.@+-]+)/$', views.search_view, name='search_view')
```

Any idea what it could be ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `?P` means in a regex. It states that the group is a named group, which is captured and sent to a view by a keyword argument. The URL that would satisfy that regex is like this:

```
/library/search/harrypotter/
```

But that's not at all what you want from a search; you want something like the one you have created, ie `library/search/?P=harry+potter`. For that you just want a URL without parameters:

```
r'^search/$'
```

and get the data in the view:

```
query = request.GET['p']
```

although you probably want to use `q` rather than `p`.

Comment: Thanks very much, especially for explaining it in detail. I definitely learnt something today for sure. Thanks for taking your time to help out.